# Anyone knows why the label of picker in react native doesn't work?

Tags: react-native

I was trying to solve the problem by removing the item from  but it seems didn't work. i wonder, am i forgot to pass something into the command?

hopefully, the screen and my code will make my explanation more briefly

Here is my code

EmployeeCreate.js

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import { Picker, Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { employeeUpdate } from '../actions'; 
import {Card,CardSection,Input,Button} from './common';


class EmployeeCreate extends Component {
   render () {
      return (
       <Card>
          <CardSection>
             <Input 
             label="Name"
             placeholder="jane"

             />
          </CardSection>

          <CardSection>
             <Input 
             label="Phone"
             placeholder="08122030930"

             />
          </CardSection>

          <CardSection style={{flexDirection:'column'}}>
             <Text style={styles.pickerTextStyle}>Select your shift</Text>
            <Picker
            selectedValue={this.props.shift}
            onValueChange={day => this.props.employeeUpdate ({prop:'shift' , value: day})}
            >
               <Picker.item label="Monday" value="Monday"    />
               <Picker.item label="Tuesday" value="Tuesday"    />
               <Picker.item label="Wednesday" value="Wednesday"    />
               <Picker.item label="Thursday" value="Thursday"    />
               <Picker.item label="Friday" value="Friday"    />
               <Picker.item label="Saturday" value="Saturday"    />
               <Picker.item label="Sunday" value="Sunday"    />
            </Picker>
          </CardSection>

          <CardSection>
             <Button>
                create
             </Button>
          </CardSection>
       </Card>
      );
   }
}

const styles = {
   pickerTextStyle: {
     fontSize: 18,
     paddingLeft: 20
   }
};

const mapStateToProps =(state) => {
   const { name,phone,shift } = state.employeeForm ;
   return {name,phone,shift};
};

export default connect (mapStateToProps,{employeeUpdate}) (EmployeeCreate)
```

;

here attached also the picture of it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqM78.png)

Answer (score 0):

If the function that you mean to call is `employeeUpdate` that you have imported from `./actions`, then you should remove `this.props.`
Else, the function may need to be defined in the parent class of `EmployeeCreate`.

Comment: did you mean like this 

 <Picker
            selectedValue={shift}
            onValueChange={day => employeeUpdate ({prop:'shift' , value: day})}

Comment: If i want to define the parent class , how it should be and where to place?

Comment: yes, I believe so since you are importing `employeeUpdate` already. `this.props` got me confused cause I thought you meant a certain function in the parent class of `EmployeeCreate`

Comment: it does not work idk why, i use redux thunk on it 

I will prove you the full code to inspect if you are willing to